# Snowflake to S3 with Header

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

Does anyone know of a way to export your data from Snowflake to an S3 file with a header?

For example, I have this table:

```
Table Example:
+----+-------+
| id | group |
+----+-------+
|  1 | bob   |
|  2 | bob   |
|  3 | bob   |
|  4 | tim   |
|  5 | tim   |
|  6 | carl  |
+----+-------+
```

I want to export this data to a file that looks like this:

```
Ex.
  id group 
  1  bob   
  2  bob   
  3  bob   
  4  tim   
  5  tim   
  6  carl
```

... but I don't see an option in the Snowflake documentation to do so.

I tried a simple UNION ALL with the names of the columns unioned to the data, but that places my header record randomly in the file.

```
Ex. 
  1  bob   
  2  bob   
  3  bob   
  4  tim 
  id group   
  5  tim   
  6  carl
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the copy option HEADER = TRUE | FALSE in your Copy_into Location statement.

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#optional-parameters

Comment: Also note that if this option is used and the COPY INTO command creates multiple files, the header will be in every file.